# How to generate a html2canvas images with a hidden source (html) div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I am working in a project where I need to generate a profile picture of any member and its reviews, and some data, I started working with GDI, but it was so hard to understand, so I searched for other options and found [Html2Canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) that works with javascript/jquery, everything is fine, the only thing I couldn't handle, and would like to know if there is a way to hide the source html div without breaking the result image.

Ex:

This is how is it now

[image: Original code]

This is how it should look

[image: How It should be]

So, when I apply display:none on the css of the source div, the image result is like this:

[image: Broken Image]

And finally here is the code that I have so far

```
var div_to_hide = $("#mydiv:hidden");
$(function() {
    $('span.stars').stars();
});
html2canvas([document.getElementById('mydiv')], {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(canvas);
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = data;
        document.getElementById('image').appendChild(image);
    }
});
$.fn.stars = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        var val = parseFloat($(this).html());
        val = Math.round(val * 4) / 4;
        var size = Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, val))) * 16;
        var $span = $('<span />').width(size);
        $(this).html($span);
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ricardojriosr/6ap9Lx1f/8/

Now the question is how do I made this work showing only the image and not the HTML source. Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to hide it before, hide (or remove) it after the canvas is rendered.

I'm not sure why `var div_to_hide` equals `$("#mydiv:hidden");` but if you change it to `var div_to_hide = $("#mydiv");` then, on line 12, after appending the image, you can run `div_to_hide.hide();`

And to avoid a flash of the HTML content, you can use some CSS trickery to cover up the original HTML. I made an example here, but you can adjust to fit whatever your actual needs are. https://jsfiddle.net/m5zq2kzn/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I can't use absolute/relative because all the page will break th css

Comment: There are probably ways around that, I don't know the structure of the page, however. Some other things to try would be: wrapping everything a relatively positioned div like so: https://jsfiddle.net/m5zq2kzn/1/ or using relative for the image div like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m5zq2kzn/2/. Actually, after looking at it again, you might be able to just do this: https://jsfiddle.net/m5zq2kzn/5/, which shouldn't matter since that div goes away anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The solution that worked for me is a css trickery to position the div that I want to hide offscreen:

```
.offscreen {
  position:absolute;
  left:-10000px;
  top:auto;
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
```

Then use it like this:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("ticket_template"))
.then((canvas) => {
  let imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
});
```